# Security Manager for Application in Java EE/Tomcat

Tags: java, security, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I need to restrict file permissions for an application running in Tomcat.
It will be a folder on the file system, outside of the Tomcat structure, that needs read/write access and dissallow read/write to anywhere else.

**SecurityManager** would suit my needs but if I create my own SecurityManager at runtime will **this be just for the application, Tomcat or the system?** 
I only want to restrict the policies for my application.

Also in some instances Tomcat can be running **without security turned on, in this case will a SecurityManager be ignored?**

Comment: Can you explain why ordinary file system permissions are not good enough for this purpose?

Comment: The directory to be restricted is configured when the application is first started so that it runs out of the box. business requirments state that this should be controlled by the application, out of the box with no/little configuration on premise. Proposal to use security manager in traditional manner, with a policy file have not been accepted as this would mean on premise editing of a policy file.